# Is there a Latin saying equivalent to a line in Jethro Tull's "Thick as a Brick"?

Tags: identification-request, latin-language

In the (rather good) progressive rock album "Thick as a Brick" by the British band Jethro Tull in 1978, there are some lines:

> So! Where the hell was Biggles When you needed him last Saturday?
> And where were all the sportsmen Who always pulled you though?
> They're all resting down in Cornwall Writing up their memoirs
> For a paper-back edition Of the Boy Scout Manual

I have a vague memory that there is a Latin saying, equivalent to this in some sense, perhaps involving Horatio Cocles, but I can find no trace of this online. Can anyone help please? I have tried hard to find this, but cannot. If no-one has a direct hit, is there an online compendium of Latin epigrams which might contain this?

I think the point of the Tull quote is that a person (particularly a boy) can't rely on fictional or historical characters, sportsmen or other celebrities: but must make his own decisions in this world. Since "there is nothing new under the sun" (Ecclesiastes and various earlier equivalent sayings) it's not surprising if there was an earlier equivalent of this observation.

Comment: Biggles is a fictional character - it's no surprise he didn't turn up "last Saturday" when you "needed him"...!

Comment: Personally, I expect there is a lot of colourful equivalents in many languages and many times - it's after all, a universal human experience to discover that back up didn'tvturn up at the right time, if at all. Is there any reason why you would want to connect this to Jethro Tull - were they classicists by any chance interested in that era of Roman history?

Comment: I see literature is no different from other se sites: drive-by downvoting of the newcomer with no explanation :)

Comment: @Mozibur Ullah - I really appreciate your responses - I will add what I think is the meaning

Comment: Odd - someone wise has silently removed the tag: "Latin-literature". But given this is from thousands of years ago in a largely dead language, how would we know about it except for literature?

Comment: Sorry about that; I guess someone misunderstood what your question is about. The [tag:latin-literature] tag is for questions about literature originally written in Latin, but it seems you *are* seeking something originally in Latin, namely some sort of quote or saying, rather than your question being directly about the quoted song lyrics. I've removed the [tag:song-lyrics] tag and added [tag:latin-literature] and [tag:identification-request].

Comment: I'm curious @Randal'Thor, why would you remove [tag:song-lyrics]? If someone came to this site and wanted to know what questions had been asked about song lyrics, wouldn't we want this one to show up there?

Comment: @verbose Unless I'm misunderstanding, this question isn't actually *about* song lyrics as such: it's just using a Tull quote as a convenient way to demonstrate a philosophical point and then asking for a Latin source that makes the same point. Even an expert in Jethro Tull lyrics might not know anything about, or even be interested in, the answer to this question - it's an ID request for a piece of Latin literature.

Comment: True enough, but someone researching what questions were asked about song lyrics would probably want to see this one; if they decide it doesn't count, that's fine, but removing the tag preempts that decision.